# Rails: Display database information based on user selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form where a user picks a date range call it

```
Borrow_date
Return_date
```

and based on this date range certain items become available. So we can call this

```
Bicycles.available_based_on_date(borrow_date, return_date)
```

basically, the above function takes in two dates and gives the bicycles available during those dates.

The problem is I want to do it dynamically in the form. So the user picks

```
<%= form.date_field :Borrow_date, min: Date.today%>
<%= form.date_field :Return_date, min: Date.today%>
```

and based on what the user selects I want to show them what is available. How do I that? I tried JS, but eventually realized I couldn't make a query with JS data.

I've read JSON is the way to go, but I couldn't find out exactly how to do that. (If that is the correct way to go about it.)

Comment: You can use Ajax to get `Bicycles.available_based_on_date` (which will be defined as a scope in `Bicycle` model) and show them on your form with a jQuery/javascript small script. What have you tried so far? Show us your view code.

Comment: How do I use Ajax to do that? I am not familiar with it. Also, the Bicycle function I mentioned is already implemented and works. I just do not know how to get that front end information to make a backend call and display that.

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain as Gerry said you need to show us some html code. The general flow would be to use javascript or jquery to grab the appropriate html element values, make an ajax.post request to send the value sto the backend, setup ruby to accept such a request by adding a post route that points to a specific controller, then in that controller do what you want to do and reply back using json to the ajax request. When you get the data back from the rails then you use the appropriate html selectors to display or whatever you intended to do

Comment: you'll need to do some research - stack overflow will help you with specific problems but not with general "how do I use ajax" questions. nor will it write code for you.
  Try this to start:  https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `ajax` (with jQuery) to get the data to populate another `select` box; consider that is a basic form (i adapted some code i already had) and you will need to customize for your specific needs. That said, it is fully functional and will get you going.

#### Form

First you need to set up your form, this example shows just the relevant code to show you how to work with ajax:

```
<form id="my-form" action="/bicycles" method="post">
  <select id="borrow-date" class="my-date">
    <option value="" selected>-- select date --</option>
    <option value="2017-05-17">05-17-2017</option>
    <option value="2017-05-18">05-18-2017</option>
    <option value="2017-05-19">05-19-2017</option>
  </select>
  <select id="return-date" class="my-date">
    <option value="" selected>-- select date --</option>
    <option value="2017-05-17">05-17-2017</option>
    <option value="2017-05-18">05-18-2017</option>
    <option value="2017-05-19">05-19-2017</option>
  </select>
  <select id="bikes">
    <option value="">-- select bicycle --</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

As you can see, the `select` with `id="bikes"` has no options, that's just a placeholder to set the real options once you get them back (from the `ajax` call). Also notice that both date `select` boxes have the same `class="my-date", this is important to get the values from each of them.

#### Script

Next, set up a `script` (this example uses jQuery, but you case javascript as well) that will get the values from both date `select` boxes and send them to your controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-date').on('change', function() {
      var data = {}

      $('.my-date').each(function() {
        if($(this).val()) {
          data[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
        }
      });

      if(Object.keys(data).length > 1) {
        $.ajax({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
          type: "POST",
          url:  "<%= bikes_path %>",
          data: data
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The above script uses only one validation (i.e. that both dates are selected), but you can add as many as you need.

Also notice how the script iterates each element with class `"my-date"` to set values into `data` variable. `data` will have two values: `borrow-date` and `return-date` (the ids of your date `select` boxes).

#### Controller

Next add an acrion to your controller (or use an existing one) to get the values (which will be available in `params`, as `:borrow_date` and `:return-date`) and use them to query your model `Bicycle`, something like this:

```
def bikes
  @bikes = Bicycle.available_based_on_date(params[:borrow_date], params[:return_date])
end
```

Notice the use of `bikes` action, which is the same route specified in your `ajax` call (in `url:  "<%= bikes_path %>"`).

#### View

Finally set your view that will add your options to the `select` that was set as a placeholder (`id="bikes"`):

```
var options = "";

<% @bikes.each do |bike| %>
  options += "<option value='<%= bike.id %>'><%= bike.name %></option>"
<% end %>

$('#bikes').html(options);
```

This view must follow the same naming convention as a `html` view, but using `js` instead of `html` (i.e. `bikes.js.erb`), since the controller needs to respond with that format to the `ajax` request.

Because this view is also `erb` you can use ruby the same way you will in any view, so we iterate `@bikes` and assign an `option` for each one of them and add those to your `select` box.

Comment: Thank you so much for typing this out. It helps a ton. I am having trouble with the view part. Is it because I am attempting to use a partial: <%= render :partial => 'form.js.erb', :locals => { ....} %> or does that not matter? The other issue might be my date_fields are not passing params, but I am not sure how to check this...

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain Rendering from a partial doesn't matter, as long as you have your endpoint set correctly (that is, the action controller that will fetch the data for the bicycles (`bikes` in my example). What exactly is your problem using the view? Do you get any error?

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain To check if your date_fields are passing params, just check your server logs. Every request is logged with the parameters from that request, including the ajax calls.

Comment: Per your advice I get this message "Started POST "/requests" for ::1 at 2017-05-22 11:59:55 -0700
Processing by RequestsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"Borrow_d"=>"2017-05-23", "Return_d"=>"2017-05-25"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)" Not sure what it means >.<   looking at this maybe my @bikes needs to be in create and not new in my rails controller as well...

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain Can you post your view/partial code? It will be faster to spot the issue that way. In fact, i recommend posting a new question with your current issue and code, that way you won't change the scope of this one and, better yet, more users are likely to jump in.

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain ohh i see, add this to your ajax call: `headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },`, check the updated answer.

Comment: Hey Gerry, I will try that, but I also made an updated post which is way more specific to the issue I am having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44120831/how-to-display-a-selection-based-on-user-input-using-ajax-and-jquery thank you again for all your help.