# How to display a selection based on user input using ajax and jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Think of the below as a bike rental. Someone fills out a form and gets a bike assigned to them which they can rent and borrow for a certain amount of time.

The problem I am having is I am trying to show the person who wants to rent the bikes what bikes are available before they submit the form. Below is my attempt using ajax. I have no errors but also my select is not updating.

request controller methods below

```
 def new
    @bikes = Bike.available_based_on_request_date(params[:Borrow_date], params[:Return_date])
    @new_request = Request.new
  end
```

create method below (with a temporary workaround, that reloads the form with a warning about availability.)

```
 def create
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    available_bikes = @request.new_request(current_user.id) 
    if (available_bikes >= @request.number_of_bikes_wanted) && @request.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:warning] = "You have requested more bikes than available. There are only #{available_bikes} bikes available"
      redirect_to new_request_url
    end
  end
```

params in request controller

```
 def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:Borrow_time, :Borrow_date,
                                    :Return_date, :Return_time,
                                    :number_of_bikes_wanted, bike_ids: [])
  end
```

new.html.erb view

```
  <div class="form" align = "center">
   <%= render 'form.js.erb'  %>
  </div>
```

_form.js.erb below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.my-date').on('change', function() {
     var data = {}

     $('.my-date').each(function() {
       if($(this).val()) {
         data[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
       }
     });

     if(Object.keys(data).length > 1) {
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: <%= new_request_path %>,
         data: data
       });
     }
   });
 });

var options = "";

<% @bikes.each do |bike| %>
options += "<option value='<%= bike.id %>'><%= bike.name %></option>"
<% end %>

$('#request_number_of_bikes_wanted').html(options);
</script>


<div class="block-it" align=center>
<br>
<%= form_for @new_request do |request| %>

<%= request.label :Borrow_date, 'Borrow on' %>
<%= request.date_field :Borrow_date, id: 'Borrow_date', class: 'my-date', min: Date.today, :required => true %>

<%= request.label :Borrow_time, 'Borrow at' %>
<%= request.time_field :Borrow_time, value: '10:00', min: '9:00 AM', max: '4:30 PM', default: '10:00 AM', :ignore_date => true, :required => true %>
<br><br>
<%= request.label :Return_date, 'Return On' %>
<%= request.date_field :Return_date, id: 'Return_date', class: 'my-date', min: Date.today, :required => true %>

<%= request.label :Return_time, 'Return at' %>
<%= request.time_field :Return_time, value: '10:00', min: '9:00 AM', max: '4:30 PM', default: '10:00 AM', :ignore_date => true, :required => true %>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<%= request.label :NumberOfBikesWanted, 'Number of bikes' %>
<%= request.select :number_of_bikes_wanted, %w(select_bike), :required => true %>
<br>
<%= request.submit 'Submit' %>
<%= request.submit 'Reset', :type => 'reset' %>
<% end %>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing your `.js.erb` view, should be `new.js.erb`, can you post it as well? Although i will recommend using a different endpoint (not `new`) for fetching the bikes. You could either use a custom action or create a new controller (both approaches will work fine).

Comment: One more thing, your form should be `_form.html.erb` since it is renderin `html`. The `.js` template should be used only in the endpoint (i.e. action) that will fetch the bikes.

Comment: I am still a bit confused I am sorry! So, if I am using   resources :requests, and this is form that creates a new request. Am I suppose to remap that in rails routes? since by default it is known as request/new.html.erb with new as the action. How exactly do I change it to new.js.erb in routes. If new is also the wrong approach do I render a partial inside the _form.html.erb for the js.erb view? I am sorry If I sound all backwards. Just trying to get this right. I appreciate your help! *EDIT* added new.html.erb view to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a two main problems with your code:

#### Controller

Use a different action to set the endpoint that you will call with ajax, so instead of this:

```
def new
    @bikes = Bike.available_based_on_request_date(params[:Borrow_date], params[:Return_date])
    @new_request = Request.new
end
```

Try this:

```
def bikes
    @bikes = Bike.available_based_on_request_date(params[:Borrow_date], params[:Return_date])

def new
    @new_request = Request.new
end
```

If you want to keep REST routes, then create a new controller and use the `index` action within that controller.

### Form

This code:

```
var options = "";

<% @bikes.each do |bike| %>
  options += "<option value='<%= bike.id %>'><%= bike.name %></option>"
<% end %>

$('#request_number_of_bikes_wanted').html(options);
```

doesn't belong here, it must be deleted from your file and instead put it on a new file called `bikes.js.erb`; also rename your form to `_form.html.erb`.

And update your ajax call to use your new route:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: <%= bikes_path %>, 
  data: data
});
```

---

What you want to setup is a new endpoint but instead of returning `html`, it will return a `js`. But you must treat it as an independent action, just as any other action in rails. The only difference is how you call that action (`ajax`) and how you respond to it (`js`).

Comment: So, I was wondering how I write the route:   post 'request/bikes'          => 'bike#index' but since it is a js.erb....sorry a bit confused here.

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain Yes, that will be your route. You will define it exactly the same as you will define any other resource/route. The fact that your controller will respond with `js` vs `html` makes no difference.

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain That route will be ok _only_ if you created a new controller named `bike` with a `index` action, otherwise, if you added `bikes` action to your current `request controller`, then it should be: `'request/bikes' => 'request#bikes'`.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I understand that now. My select always says "select_bike" and never changes. Referring to: <%= request.label :NumberOfBikesWanted, 'Number of bikes' %>
<%= request.select :number_of_bikes_wanted, %w(select_bike), :required => true %>. I looked over everything and am unsure at what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain Do you get any error in your logs? Also, can you confirm that `request_number_of_bikes_wanted` is `id` of the `select` box? Also, check your console messages (if any) in your browser (using dev tools).

Comment: I forgot to put the url in quotes, however I am getting the following error: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RequestController):. So my route, is with bikes in my request controller. I created a file called bikes.js.erb and it is in the requests view folder. My route is 'request/bikes' => 'request#bikes'. I checked rake routes. It is showing up as /request/bikes and it shows that in the ajax call too... not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144875/discussion-between-gerry-and-codingdraculasbrain).

Comment: This is definitely the solution! Thanks for all the help.